# Content won't stay inside div

Tags: css

Hope I don't seem like too much of a newbie developer with this problem but I can't for the life of me seem to find the right combination of techniques to get this to work. Essentially, when in mobile view I have a div that populates with image data once searched and when that happens all of my menu icons get pushed somewhere else instead of staying put. Shouldn't the image data be confined to the div? I've tried position absolute, position fixed, overflow:hidden, hard coding the height in pixels, using flex-wrap and other flex properties, among other things. Nothing has worked so far. Check it out here: https://craftyquotes-bja.herokuapp.com/  Click on the camera button, search for any image genre and see what happens. That's the issue. Any hints or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

You have a class "pic-render "inside" pic-render", I do not know why, but in my opinion it is not necessary. Add a pair of properties to the nested div tags.

```
<style>
    .form_container {
        height: 5vh;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .image_container {
        height: 63vh;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
<div class="pic-render">
    <div class="form_container">
        <form>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="searchValue" placeholder="Search Images">
            <button>SEARCH</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="image_container">
        <img src="">
        ...
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks a ton! If its not too much to ask Do you mind explaining your thought process and how you arrived at the solution? If not, no big deal you're already a life saver.

Comment: You have a "pic-render" container, you set it a height of 68vh, now it has 2 elements inside it - a form and a container for images, you set the height separately for the form (5vh) and set " overflow: hidden", so that the form content does not fly out of bounds. next, set the image container height to 63vh (63vh+5vh=68vh is your content provider), and use the "overflow: auto" property to scroll through the content inside the block. This way the form is always visible, and the images are scrolled through